# vb.net array list won't load

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am absolutely new to VB.NET, i've done some vbS a long time ago.

Now I am trying to make a MVP kinda system and I am trying to define and load an array, through the system. Then read it out and it should populate a ListView1 object.

Can anyone shine some light on why it doesn't populate. I know they are set correct, because the console tells me it's set ok.

I know the sample would fill with the same item (a week to be exact) every time i add an item, but that's not the point.

Also, is it possible to define the array without the index, i mean now i set it with (6) so it sets 6 blocks for strings, but I would like to be more flexible.

Is there a way like in php for example
$item["firstname"]
$item["lastname"]
...

thanks you for your time and effort! :-)

ClientlistItem.vb (definition of the actual item)

```
Public Class ClientlistItem

    Private entry(6) As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal iEntry() As String)
        entry(0) = iEntry(0)
        entry(1) = iEntry(1)
        entry(2) = iEntry(2)
        entry(3) = iEntry(3)
        entry(4) = iEntry(4)
        entry(5) = iEntry(5)
    End Sub

End Class
```

ClientList.vb (The model as it were)

Imports System.Collections.Generic

```
Public Class Clientlist
    Public Event ClientlistChanged()
    Private mItems As List(Of ClientlistItem) = New List(Of ClientlistItem)

    Public ReadOnly Property Items() As List(Of ClientlistItem)
        Get
            Return mItems
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub AddItem(ByRef iEntry() As String)
        Console.WriteLine(iEntry(0))

        Dim item As ClientlistItem = New ClientlistItem(iEntry)
        mItems.Add(item)
        RaiseEvent ClientlistChanged()
    End Sub
End Class
```

ClientlistPresenter.vb (the presenter)

```
Public Class ClientlistPresenter
    Private iEntry() As String
    Private mClientlistModel As Clientlist
    Private mClientlistView As ClientlistView

    Public Sub New(ByRef view As ClientlistView)
        mClientlistModel = New Clientlist
        mClientlistView = view
        mClientlistView.Init(mClientlistModel, Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddItem(ByVal iEntry() As String)
        mClientlistModel.AddItem(iEntry)
    End Sub
End Class
```

ClientlistView.vb (the view.. this has the LIstview I would like to fill)

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ClientlistView
    Private mClientlistPresenter As ClientlistPresenter
    Private WithEvents mClientlistModel As Clientlist

    Private Sub OrderView_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        mClientlistPresenter = New ClientlistPresenter(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Orderview_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

        Dim fWidth As Integer = Me.Width
        Dim fHeight As Integer = Me.Height
        ListView1.Bounds = New Rectangle(New Point(0, 25), New Size(fWidth, fHeight))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init(ByRef model As Clientlist, ByRef presenter As ClientlistPresenter)

        mClientlistPresenter = presenter
        mClientlistModel = model


        ' Set the view to show details.
        listView1.View = View.Details
        ' Allow the user to rearrange columns.
        listView1.AllowColumnReorder = True
        ' Display check boxes.
        listView1.CheckBoxes = True
        ' Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
        listView1.FullRowSelect = True
        ' Display grid lines.
        listView1.GridLines = True
        ' Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
        listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
        ListView1.Columns.Add("#", 40, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Wholename", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Date of birth", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        listView1.Columns.Add("Country of birth", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

        ' Add the ListView to the control collection.
        Me.Controls.Add(listView1)


    End Sub

    Private Sub ClientlistChanged() Handles mClientlistModel.ClientlistChanged


        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        Dim i As Object
        For Each i In mClientlistModel.Items()

        Next

    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim week(6) As String
        week(0) = "Sunday"
        week(1) = "Monday"
        week(2) = "Tuesday"
        week(3) = "Wednesday"
        week(4) = "Thursday"
        week(5) = "Friday"
        week(6) = "Saturday"

        mClientlistPresenter.AddItem(week)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to populate the ListView exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the "New ClientlistItem(iEntry)" call in Clientlist.AddItem, you are putting the iEntry elements into the private ClientlistItem.entry member. How exactly did you plan to make the data in "Private entry(6) As String" accessible outside of ClientlistItem?

One solution is to create a Property inside of ClientlistItem:

```
 Public ReadOnly Property Items As String()
    Get
        Return entry
    End Get
 End Property
```

Put this inside your Button1_Click function at the end to confirm that values are getting in and staying in:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To mClientlistModel.Items.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To mClientlistModel.Items(i).Items.Count - 1
            Debug.Print(String.Format("item({0},{1})=", i, j) + mClientlistModel.Items(i).Items(j))
        Next
    Next
    Stop
```

The "Immediate" window of the IDE should show something like:

```
item(0,0)=Sunday
item(0,1)=Monday
item(0,2)=Tuesday
item(0,3)=Wednesday
item(0,4)=Thursday
item(0,5)=Friday
item(0,6)=
```

That above list should grow with every button click.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that "Public ReadOnly Property Items As String()" will nonetheless allow the elements to be modified. If you really wanted them read-only, you'll need to make a "Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As String" and maybe also a "Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer" too.